# Error(1,30): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a procedure using oracle, it should be working fine but i keep getting the following error:

> Error(1,30): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior

here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale () 
BEGIN  
ALTER TABLE Product_T ADD COLUMN SalePrice decimal(6,2);

UPDATE Product 
SET SalePrice = .90 * ProductStandardPrice 
WHERE ProductStandardPrice >= 400; 

UPDATE Product 
SET SalePrice = .85 * ProductStandardPrice 
WHERE ProductStandardPrice < 400; 

END
```

Comment: I think you can only use parentheses when there are actually arguments.  Remove the `()`.

Comment: I tried removing the parantheses and it threw this error `Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled    wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined    result_cache accessible`

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  Adding a column in a procedure is rather strange.  That would mean that the procedure could only ever be called successfully once-- after that, it would fail because the DDL was no longer valid.  Either you are trying to install/ update an application in which case that shouldn't be a procedure or you have something that you want to run repeatedly in which case you wouldn't include the DDL.

Comment: Also, PL/SQL has no 'ALTER' statement, and 'ALTER TABLE ... ADD' has no 'COLUMN' keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale
AS BEGIN  

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Product_T ADD COLUMN SalePrice decimal(6,2)';

    UPDATE Product 
        SET SalePrice = (CASE WHEN ProductStandardPrice >= 400 THEN 0.90 ELSE 0.85 END) * ProductStandardPrice 
END;
```

Notes:

- Removed the parentheses.
- Moved the `alter` to dynamic SQL.
- Combined the two updates into a single statement.
- Added `AS` before `BEGIN`.

I think the `update` is okay, but it might also need to be dynamic SQL.

EDIT:

I was thinking that Oracle delayed the interpretation of the queries until the stored procedure is run.  But you should use dynamic SQL throughout:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale
AS BEGIN  

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Product_T ADD COLUMN SalePrice decimal(6,2)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
UPDATE Product 
    SET SalePrice = (CASE WHEN ProductStandardPrice >= 400 THEN 0.90 ELSE 0.85 END) * ProductStandardPrice 
';
END;
```

Comment: I tried what you have above, still gave me errors. I added `As` before `Begin` and moved the alter to a dynamic sql. I guess it does not recognize that I altered the table Product as it throws: `Error(6,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SALEPRICE": invalid identifier`

Comment: Awesome, that made it compile. how do i go about calling that procedure though? when i do `Call productlinesale;` it says it's not a valid procedure.

Comment: @AliElsaadi . . . `call` is not necessary in PL/SQL blocks.

Comment: Please add some more details about how you're calling it. If you've just created a procedure and it's valid, you shouldn't be getting 'not a valid procedure' when you call it, so either you didn't create it, or it isn't valid, or you're calling it wrong. You should just be getting the syntax error from the dynamic 'alter' statement (try it on its own first). Then after it's run successfully once, you'll get a different error because a table can only have one 'saleprice' column.